# Max and min of $f(x,y)=(x+y)e^{(-y^2+x)}$ on $D$

Tags: real-analysis

$D=\{(x,y)\in R^2: x^2+2xy+y^2-2x-2y+1=0\}$.
In fact $D=\{(x,y): x+y-1=0\}$ but my book has the solution $(1/2,1/2)$ and i found the max$(3/2, -1/2).$

Have I made a mistake?

$f(1-y,y)=e^{(....)} (-1-2y)$

Comment: Have you used Lagrange multiplicators?

Comment: Tell us what you did and we'll be happy to find your mistake if you made any :)

Comment: @user495707 your (3/2,-1/2) is fine for me, but $f(1-y,y)=e^{(....)} (-1-2y)$ is $f$ or $ f'$?

Answer (score -1):

[edited due to a change in the original post]

There is no need for Lagrange multipliers here... Since over $D$ we have $y = 1-x$, just make that substitution in the objective function and optimize over $\mathbb{R}$.  More precisely, over $D$, you can optimize

$$
g(y)=f(1-y,y)=e^{-y^2-y+1},
$$

or just $-y^2-y+1$, that will share the same optimum points. In this case, you will find a maximum point for $y = - \frac 12$ ( and $x = \frac 32$).

Comment: You apparently uploaded in another function (exponential part?)

Comment: The expression of the objective function was corrected... I replied with respect to the original post...

Comment: I edited the post. thanks.